# Add html content to js generated class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, dynamically-generated

I have a trivial issue and need your help. Thanks to you, I have 2690 squares generated by js:

```
var i, square, text, container = document.getElementById("square_container");
for (i = 1; i <= 2690; i += 1) {
    square = document.createElement("div");
    square.id = "square" + i;
    square.classList.add("square");
    text = document.createElement("h1");
    text.innerHTML = i;
    text.id = "text" + i;
    square.appendChild(text);
    container.appendChild(square);
    text.classList.add("hover");
}
```

The code above generate 2690 of this:

```
<div id="square1" class="square"><h1 id="text1">1</h1></div>
```

And now, I need to add following html content to each .square class:

```
<div class="hover"><a href="#">Click Me</a></div>
```

So in the result I need to have:

```
<div id="square1" class="square"><h1 id="text1">1</h1>

<div class="hover"><a href="#">Click Me</a>

</div>
</div>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/tynw5c34/3/

I tried .append, .addClass...but it doesn't work. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: *How* did you "*try `append()`, .`addClass()`...*"? In what way does it not work? Looking at your posted code you appear to be using plain JavaScript (which is absolutely fine), are you really using jQuery (you really don't have to, it's entirely optional)?

Comment: I tried this way: `$( ".square" ).append( "<p>example</p>" );` but it doesn't work.

Comment: But.. why are you not generating the "Click me" HTML when you generate your square ? + Can you show us a sample of what $(".square") return in your console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lukas. To achieve the function you were looking for using jQuery, I added an external resource:

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js

and added this to the javascript:

```
$( ".square" ).append("<div class=\"hover\"><a href=\"#\">Click Me</a></div>")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 2690; i += 1) {
    square = document.createElement("div");
    square.id = "square" + i;
    square.classList.add("square");
    text = document.createElement("h1");
    text.innerHTML = i;
    text.id = "text" + i;
    square.appendChild(text);
    container.appendChild(square);
    $('#square'+i).append('<div class="hover"><a href="#">Click Me</a></div>');
}
```

If you want generate squares with Javascript, use this :

```
var i, square, text, container = document.getElementById("square_container");
var content = document.createElement('div');
content.className = 'hover';
var a=document.createElement('a');
a.href='#';
a.innerHTML='Click Me';
content.appendChild(a);
for (i = 1; i <= 2690; i += 1) {
    square = document.createElement("div");
    square.id = "square" + i;
    square.classList.add("square");
    text = document.createElement("h1");
    text.innerHTML = i;
    text.id = "text" + i;
    square.appendChild(text);
    container.appendChild(square);
    document.getElementById('square'+i).appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
}
```

You need to use `cloneNode()` method , which clones all attributes and values of specified element. A node can't be in two locations in the tree at once.

Here is a working solution: [jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tynw5c34/5/)

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with javascript version if help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the html in pure javascript like this

```
 var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
    var str = '<div class="hover"><a href="#">Click Me</a> </div>';
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(squares, function(sqr, index) 
    {
         sqr.innerHTML = sqr.innerHTML + str;
    });
```

Working fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/egxbhehu/

Answer (score 0):

The append function should work. 
Also, please note that `<h1></h1>` tag should be used only once per page. Consider using `<span></span>` and CSS to make it look like your current h1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should use createDocumentFragment() to append multiple childs.

```
    var i, square, text, hoverDiv, aHref, container = document.getElementById("square_container");
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i += 1) {
    square = document.createElement("div");
    square.id = "square" + i;
    square.classList.add("square");
    text = document.createElement("h1");
    text.innerHTML = i;
    text.id = "text" + i;
    hoverDiv = document.createElement("div");
    hoverDiv.classList.add("hover");
    aHref = document.createElement("a");
    aHref.href = "#";
    aHref.innerHTML = "Click Me";
    hoverDiv.appendChild(aHref);
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    docFrag.appendChild(text);
    docFrag.appendChild(hoverDiv);
    square.appendChild(docFrag);
    container.appendChild(square);
}
```